# Will selenium react or bond, ionic or covalent, with vanadium?

Tags: metal, ionic-compounds, covalent-compounds

I was recently asked if $\ce{Se}$ will bond with $\ce{V}$, creating a compound $\ce{SeV}$ . I am not sure if this is even possible but if so I'd like to find out.

Comment: Afaik, selenides are quite hard to prepare and require smelting of the elements or use of transport reaction.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022190266800088

Answer (score 4):

The ASM Alloy Phase Diagram Database (at asminternational.org if you have access) shows that $V_{2}Se_{9}$, $V_{5}Se_{8}$, $V_{3}Se_{4}$ $V_{5}Se_{4}$, and $VSe$ are all accepted stable phases in the Se-V binary system.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much. This has helped me out a lot.  @joncluster